# How to check condition in dictionary?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

How to check that all  the keys and their values are same in dictionary?
what would be the fastest way to acheve this?

```
{2: 2, 4: 2, 1: 1} #print false
{4: 4, 2: 2, 1: 1} # print true
```

Comment: `all(key == value for key, value in d.items())`

Answer (score 3):

Using `all`

**Ex:**

```
data = [{2: 2, 4: 2, 1: 1}, {4: 4, 2: 2, 1: 1}]
for i in data:
    if all(k==v for k,v in i.items()):
        print(True)
    else:
        print(False)
```

**Output:**

```
False
True
```

Comment: `for i in data: print(all(k==v for k,v in i.items()))` is enough. `if-else` statements are redundant here.

Answer (score 0):

you can use comprehension

```
print(False) if any([item1!=item2 for item1, item2 in dict.items()]) else print(True)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
for k, v in dictionary.items():
    if k != v:
        return false
    return true
```

Comment: While this code may work as a solution, it is better to add context, and explain your code. This helps future visitors hone in on what is important to pay attention to in this code, and helps others learn, so they can apply this knowledge to their own code. Or address how/why this code differs from the OP's attempts and contrast why this solution works. This keeps SO quality high, discourages "give me the code" questions, and encourages sharing *knowledge & information*. Visitors are more likely to pay attention to & read informative posts. High quality Answers are more likely to get "upvotes"

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
all(dict[key]==key for key in dict)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `Xor` to compare each value.

```
result = True if sum([d[i] ^ i for i in d]) == 0 else False
```

**Edited to remove redundancies:**

```
result = sum([d[i] ^ i for i in d]) == 0
```

Comment: `True if … else False` does not add any value.

Answer (score 0):

One-liner:

```
print(True) if list(d.keys())==list(d.values()) else print(False)
```

Answer (score 0):

***all(key==value for key,value in d.items())***

all is special function in python , which will retrun True only if all the elements satisfy the condition,